# Case-sensitive Google search

Tags: google-search

Is there any way to make a Google search case-sensitive?

Comment: I‘d like to search for videos on "cURL like a pro" to make web downloads, instead of how to curl your hair. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, from "[Google search basics: Basic search help](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=134479)":

> Search is always case insensitive. A search for [ new york times ] is the same as a search for [ New York Times ].

Comment: The quoted text has changed, very likely because it was misleading. `new york times` is the same as `New York Times`, but it is not the same as `"New York Times"`.  `OR` is considered a search operator but  `or` not.