# Does case:yes make Google Search case-sensitive?

Tags: google-search

I'm not duplicating [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/4452) because it's from 2010 and doesn't mention `case:yes`. [Enabling case-sensitive searches  |  Code Search  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/code-search/user/case-sensitive-search)

> [image]

But [`case:yes "unclear is if"`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=case%3Ayes+%22unclear+is+if%22) didn't work?

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link you are referring to *"[Enabling case-sensitive searches  |  Code Search  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/code-search/user/case-sensitive-search)"* is about searching the code within your projects and not about Google Search.
As stated within the page:

> To get started, open the Code Search UI for your project
>
> - Android
> - Chromium
> - Other Google Projects: Google Open Source

Google Search is [case insensitive](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479):

> **Tip 4: Don’t worry about the little things**
>
> - **Spelling**. Google's spell checker automatically uses the most common spelling of a given word, whether or not you spell it
>     correctly.
> - **Capitalization**. A search for *New York Times* is the same as a search for *new york times*.

Comment: This answer is good, but it would be awesome if there was some information on whether there is *any* way to do a case-sensitive search on Google or another platform

Comment: I came across the same Code Search example at Google Developers as I was searching the web for answers, and I came to the same conclusion: `case:yes` is only useful in a `"Code Search"` context. Can you imagine, Google doesn't know how to do a case sensitive search? Pathetic! This is known as "innovation" nowadays.

Comment: What's really stupid is that Google can't do a case sensitive search in any context, not just in the realm of the mighty Google Search. They can't do a case sensitive search in Google Workspace or in Google Mail (Gmail) either. This is why they had to "invent" the case of `case:yes` to please developers. Would it kill them to at least give us an option for doing a case sensitive search, even if case insensitive search is the default? To Google, I suppose, we are all the same: stupid mass that needs help from big brother to think clearly and to function in the world.

Comment: A decade ago, Amit Agarwal had a good blog post about [Google's insensitivity](https://www.labnol.org/internet/search/case-sensitive-google-search/6279/). Apparently, someone made a [search engine](https://code.google.com/archive/p/case-sensitive-search/source) that eats Google's search engine for breakfast, in order to produce case sensitive results. Sometimes, revenge is a beautiful thing. An eye for an aye; an engine for an engine. It's OK to reinvent the wheel when the original wheel is not spinning properly.

Comment: Yes, don't worry if it's impossible to search for how to restore windows after a reboot on a Linux system rather than finding out how to reinstall Windows because Google knows better and doesn't want you to sweat the small stuff like actually getting relevant search results.